# Sockets used to send messages between machines

Tags: python-3.7

I want to make a sort of chat server between my desktop and my laptop using sockets. Does anybody know of a good tutorial on this or if you have any files with comments on it that I can use as reference?

Answer (score 0):

This could be good at the beginning of your adventure:
https://medium.com/swlh/lets-write-a-chat-app-in-python-f6783a9ac170

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely read this. Looks interesting and helpful!